# Why does Web Platform Installer not present .NET Framework 4.6.x for installation?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net, web-platform-installer

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 web server and I need to deploy .NET Framework 4.6.x (probably 4.6.2). I cannot seem to find this version in Web Platform Installer 5.0.

It does however offer .NET Framework 4.5.2, indicating correctly that it has already been installed.

I know I could hunt down the manual installer for .NET Framework 4.6.2, but I like using the Web Platform Installer for this sort of thing because it (so far) has always installed the correct version of everything I've needed without incident.

Does anyone know what hoops I need to jump through to get this working?

**UPDATE**

Well, I just did a successful manual install of .NET Framework 4.6.2 and it all came up fine after a reboot. This can be my workaround when we deploy to production but I'd like to understand what's going on with Web Platform Installer.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because that version of the Web Platform Installer was released in 2013 and .NET Framework 4.6 wasn't released until 2015.

Comment: Yet .NET Framework 4.5.2 which IS being offered was released in 2014, so just being newer than Web Platform Installer 5.0 doesn't seem to rule out a package's availablity.

Comment: It seems offline installer of the target .NET framework is the only way to go.